# Show that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) = \{0\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) = \{0\}$.

My attempt:

Since $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) = (-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r})$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ where $r > 1$, and $\{0\} \in (-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r})$, $\{0\} \subset \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$.

Since $\exists r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} (-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r}) \subset \{0\}$ so $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) \subset \{0\}$.

I think "calculus level" is much easier than more abstract reasoning, but perhaps this is correct? (Not that it's advanced, it's just more "reasoning" than "numbers"...)

Comment: There's a lot of math notation there that doesn't make sense, unfortunately.

Comment: Since $\exists r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} (-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r})$ ..., it doesn't make sense. $r$ is a dummy notation so you cannot say there exists an $r$.

Comment: Your combination of words and formulas makes no sense. I think you are trying to reason with formulas rather than by thinking. Here's a hint. Start with any real number $r \ne 0$ and argue (using words) that it is not in that intersection.

Comment: Thanks for input. I will try again then, with more words / thoughts... or perhaps this is not my cup of tea. (Reasoning, that is.)

Comment: Attempt 2. Take any real number $r \neq 0$. This number is not in the intersection, since if we let $N$ be the floor or $r$, $r \notin (-\frac{1}{N},\frac{1}{N}) \cap (-\frac{1}{N+1},\frac{1}{N+1})$. So $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) \subset \{0\}$. And $0 \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ since $\forall r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, $0 \in (-\frac{1}{r},\frac{1}{r})$. So $\{0\} \subset \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: It might be helpful to formally write down the definition of the statement "$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\tfrac1n = 0$". The proof then follows almost immediately from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $x \neq 0$, there is an $n$ such that $|1/n| < |x|$, namely $n > 1/|x|$.
Since any non-zero number is excluded from the region, then only $0$ can and does work.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously $0\subset\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

For $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$, then $-\frac{1}{n}<x<\frac{1}{n}$ holds for every $n$, that is
$x=0$.

Comment: This is not a proof. It's just a restatement of the question. You have to justify the "that is". Please wait for the OP to try before completing your answer.